# Fetch API data undefined

Tags: json, fetch-api

I have been trying to fetch and display data however it hasn't been displaying and when I look on the console it says "TypeError: "data.collections is undefined"" and I'm strugging to understand why. It would be great to get some help so that the text displays.

This is my code:

My JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "archives": {
      "year1": {
        "title": "Sample Title 1"
      },
      "year2": { 
        "title": "Sample Title 2"
      },
      "year3": {
        "title": "Sample Title 3"
      }
    },    
    "collections": {
      "health": {
        "title": "Sample Title 4"
      },
      "money": { 
        "title": "Sample Title 5"
      },
        "relationships": {
      "title": "Sample Title 6"
      }
    }
  } 
]
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="archives"></div>
        <div class="collections"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
        fetch('final.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Looks like there was a problem: ', error));

        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("archives");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.archives.length; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.innerHTML = 
                        '<span class="archives">' + 
                         data[i].archives.year1.title + '</span>' + 
                        '<span class="archives">' + 
                         data[i].archives.year2.title + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="archives">' + 
                         data[i].archives.year3.title + '</span>';
                     mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                }
            }

            function appendData(data) {
                var mainContainer = document.getElementById("collections");
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.collections.length; i++) {
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                            div.innerHTML = 
                            '<span class="collections">' + data[i].collections.health.title + '</span>' + 
                            '<span class="collections">' + data[i].collections.money.title + '</span>' +
                            '<span class="collections">' + data[i].collections.relationships.title + '</span>';
                        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                    }
                }
```

In the console the two lines of code showing up in the error are:

```
 appendData(data);
```

and

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.collections.length; i++) {
```

It also says:

```
 "TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference"
```

Comment: It may or may not be the problem, but you're not checking that the HTTP operation succeeded. Unfortunately, `fetch` fulfills its promise if the network operation worked, even if the HTTP operation didn't. See [my post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog, you need to check `response.ok` before calling `response.json()`.

Comment: It's confusing to have a function called `appendData` *within* a function called `appendData` as you appear to above. It's even more confusing that you don't appear to ever call the nested one, and the outer one doesn't have any closing `}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON, `data`, is an array, so the accessors `data.archives` and `data.collections` doesn't actually exist. That means that you are trying to call `undefined.length` which is where your error is coming from. You need to make your accessors be `data[0].archives` and `data[0].collections`.